# iframe not showing up in different resolutions

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an iFrame that I am using as the footer of my website. The website has scrolling disabled.

I made the website on my laptop, but then when I try it on some older computer the footer doesnt show up. Again, the website has scrolling disabled so the iframe has to show up perfect.

Right now I have the following CSS defined for this iframe:

`.footer {
margin: 260px 0 0 90px;
}`

This margin places the iframe exactly where it needs to be on my 1360 X 768 Resolution laptop.

What is the best way to do this. Using responsive or % instead of pixels?

Comment: @ManofSnow I honestly believe it's resolution of the screen. Because, even on my laptop where the website looks fine, I can change the resolution and the footer looks wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your footer probably doesn't show up because you computer has another resolution and is therefore positioning it too low. Since it's not scrollable you can't reach it.
You could position the footer absolute.

```
.footer { 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I guess the `.footer` is the iframe.

Comment: also, using .footer { 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
} did not work

Comment: @user2998050 This should work. Is your iframe inside any other element?

Comment: And did you remove the margin-top 260px?

Comment: Yes I tried all of that. Is still doesnt seem to work on all resolutions.?

Comment: @AnthonyWeber Do you have an email address that I could email you my code at?

Comment: @user2998050 Isn't it possible to put some part of your code on a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/